# Responding to one method but not to other in the same scope

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

With the following code

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ...
  # code filtered from here
  # ...

  # both methods below are public methods

  def humanized_roles
    roles.collect {|e| e.name.humanize }.join(', ')
  end

  def role=( arg = nil)
    self.roles = []
    self.add_role arg.to_sym
  end
end
```

This is happening

```
User.new.respond_to? :humanized_roles
# => false
User.new.respond_to? "role=".to_sym
# => true
```

rvm, ruby, rails versions

- rvm 1.26.3
- ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-linux]
- Rails 3.2.14

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Must be something else, the above code works as expected.

Comment: BTW, `:role=` is a valid symbol, use can use it instead of `"role=".to_sym`

Comment: Thank you @Stefan, just some old code that I do not want to keep updating for such changes every now and then, unless running a specific DRY/cleanup cycle.

Just my way of keeping business logic changes separate from all other.

Comment: Maybe `humanized_roles` is set to private or protected somewhere else. Have you checked `User.instance_methods(false)`, `User.private_instance_methods(false)` and `User.protected_instance_methods(false)`?

Comment: Defined only here. Used in views. No other occurrence.

Comment: Well, the above code snippet works and returns `true` for both `respond_to?` calls. Your problem cannot be reproduced with the given code.

Comment: I know @Stefan. But it fails at my staging server. closed this for now.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of product release, I circumvented this issue and used a helper method to accept user object as parameter, instead of user.humanize_roles

Thank you everyone for your valuable time & responses.